# Mounting large TV through a custom extension frame

Tags: structural-engineering

I need to mount a large TV (weighing about 50 lb.) to the wall. But the built-in media center (i.e., the one that is built into the wall of the house) is deep, not not tall enough to house the TV - so, I will not be able to directly use extension wall mounts (like https://mount-it.com/products/long-extension-tv-wall-mount-mi-372). So, I am planning to build a custom frame using 2x4 lumber that will attach to the built-in media center. And then, fix the wall mount (like the one listed above) on this frame. The TV will ultimately by attached to the wall mount. It will look like this:

[image: custom-frame to which a TV mount will be fixed]

My question is: will the frame built out of the 2x4s be able to support the force applied by the wall mount. The frame will be about 3 ft. long and 2 ft. high. TV will be mounted about 2 ft. from this frame (using the mounting bracket). What should I take into account for a stable design?

If this is not right forum, please recommend where I can post this

Comment: add a diagonal brace between top left and bottom right

Comment: Thanks. Received same suggestion in the other response as well. Will add this brace.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the link provided, which states that the mount can be attached to studs with sixteen or twenty-four inch spacing, one must presume that your drawing in two dimensions also provides for a second set of braces hidden/coincidental to the ones shown.

The drawing shows a stud in the wall, which also must require presumption that the mount supports will be attached to match two studs with appropriate spacing. Yet another assumption is that you will use pocket screws to secure the thirty-six inch horizontal members to the studs.

Combining the vertical supports to the horizontal supports provides for the leverage of such a long moment arm and the pocket screws should be sufficiently strong, although they will be placed in tension. I suggest combining a good quality wood glue with the screws to ensure more stability and strength. If possible, use glue at the stud and thirty-six inch interface as well.

Because the mount will be attached on the long side of the vertical support, into long grain, you'll have the best strength possible for such a mount.

Fifty pounds spread over the two studs and DIY supports should be considered a relatively mild load. If you desire to have just one more level of structural assurance, consider to add a diagonal from the top forward section to the bottom lower portion of the wall stud.

Not shown in the drawing is a face-on view, which should have at the very least, a horizontal at the top location. The bottom location is secured from torsion by the fasteners in the bottom of the assembly, attached to the entertainment center. If you suspect your mount will experience lateral movement, add one diagonal from upper right to lower left or vice versa. These diagonals can be 1x2 lumber and provide sufficient strength for your purposes.

I don't suggest that you try this, but I suspect you could suspend the maximum weight allowed by the bracket manufacturer and experience no movement.

Source: constructed something of nearly identical design (less support!) for outdoor storage of metal stock.

Comment: Thanks for the response Fred. You are correct - I am planning to have two frames like that with a horizontal bar (on the front) as you mentioned. I was going to use wood glue in addition to the pocket screws. Also, I was planning to attach both L-frames to a 1x2 or a 2x4 on both ends. That would make it easier to attach this entire setup to the wall and to the base of the entertainment center. I could even make these span across multiple studs (might not be necessary though). Thanks for the suggestion about the diagonal bars (left-right and front-back) - had not considered it.